# Error while installing angular-cli globally through cmd

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, nvm, nodist

I have been trying to install Angular CLI on my Windows system.

I am new to this, and have been following steps given in https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/learn-angular-from-scratch-step-by-step to setup my environment. Since I am using Windows, I used "nodist" NVM method to install node and npm on my system. I can successfully run both these commands hinting to the fact that perhaps npm and node have been installed correctly -

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -v
1.2.24
C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v
v0.10.9
```

Now, to install Angular CLI, I ran -

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install angular/cli
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\angular\cli'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.24
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\angular\cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried creating a folder 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\angular\cli'. Also, tried cleaning cache and retrying. But none of it helped.

**Edit :**

Okay I tried setting up through the installer file mentioned in one of the comments, and now I have node version - "10.16.3" and npm version - "6.9.0".
But running the mentioned command for installing angular-cli gives me this error :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm i -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.18.35:80
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Users\comviva\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v0.10.9\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Also, I am using a system at my office. And looking up the proxy settings at "Change Proxy Settings" on Windows, I don't see any Proxy server being used.

Comment: upgrade your node and npm versions

Comment: npm install -g npm@latest

Comment: @AhmedRebai Getting this error when I run this command : 
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:875:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong node version or the overall installation file. You can get the working version of node here https://nodejs.org/en/ and choose the recommended version for most users. go through the installation process and after that just run `npm i -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: This page https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm says  :
"We strongly recommend using a Node version manager to install Node.js and npm. We do not recommend using a Node installer, since the Node installation process installs npm in a directory with local permissions and can cause permissions errors when you run npm packages globally." And hence, I wanted to use NVM instead to install node.
Should I not?

Comment: @Ariba Siddiqui That is only if you ever gonna need different versions of node.  I never needed nvm through whole time I worked with angular. but if you read it further down there is specific nvm package for windows which is the one you should use.

Comment: @AribaSiddiqui Yeah, you need to talk to your system administrator, it can be that they have set up something to prevent such connections. Sadly this is outside of my expertise...

Comment: Thanks, I talked to the system admin and it was the proxy server setting I had to change.

Comment: @NerijusPamedytis i suggest using [nodist](https://github.com/nullivex/nodist) instead of nvm on windows, the nvm win porting is in a pretty rude state yet.